# Covariance of a 3D Gaussian and Ellipsoid

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, linear-transformations

I am reading a [paper](https://repo-sam.inria.fr/fungraph/3d-gaussian-splatting/3d_gaussian_splatting_low.pdf), where the authors compute the covariance of a 3D Gaussian $\Sigma$ as the "configuration of an ellipsoid". Specifically, Eq. 6 in the paper states that:

$$ \Sigma = R \ S \ S^T R^T$$

where $R$ and $S$ are the rotation and scaling matrices respectively.

**Questions**

I have two related two questions:

- Why is the "configuration of an ellipsoid" equal to the covariance of a 3D Gaussian? The covariance measures the relation among N random variables, while an ellipsoid is a primitive.
- Intuitively, I can see why the shape of a 3D Gaussian is given by its covariance. As far as I understand, the equation above consists in rotating and scaling a unit sphere. Why isn't just $R \ S$? I am confused by the use of the transpose of the two matrices. Mathematically, I see that $R \ S$ would not define a positive semi-definite matrix, therefore it would not be a valid covariance matrix. Still, I don't understand the intuition behind this.

**EDIT**
Thanks to some pointers in the comments below, I have understood that we can use spectral deocmposition to decompose the symmetrical covariance $\Sigma Q \ \Lambda \ Q^T$. Q and QT are orthogonal matrices, hence can be seen as a rotation matrix. Specifically, the define the rotation from the bases to the orthogonal eigenvectors. $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix containing the eigenvalues along its diagonal. Therefore,it can be seen as a scaling matrix. Isn't then $\Sigma = R \ S \ R^T$ enough? Why do we say that $\Lambda = S \ S^T$?

I have also tried to get to a similar results using the Cholesky decomposition: $\Sigma = L \ L^T$. However, I am not sure how to decompose $L = R \ S$.

Comment: Thanks @KurtG. Unfortunately that doesn't answer my question. In a nuthsell, my question is: why does $R S S^T R^T$ define the covariance of a 3D Gaussian?

Comment: You should make more effort to learn about covariance matrices. In a nutshell: they are non-negative semidefinite and have a Cholesky decomposition. Alternatively: they are symmetric and can be diagonalized using rotation matrices. What is left is $D=SS^T\,.$ What does that have to do with scaling? Think about it. It would probably help if you calculate explicitly all those matrices in a $2\times 2$ case. This can be done by hand.

Comment: @KurtG. Thanks for the pointers. Because $\Sigma$ is symmetric, we can use spectral deocmposition to obtain $\Sigma = Q \ \Lambda \ Q^T $. $Q$ and $Q^T$ are orthogonal matrices, hence can be seen as a rotation matrix. $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix, hence can be seen as a scaling matrix. Isn't then $\Sigma = R \ \Lambda R^T$ enough? (I have also tried to get to a similar results using the Cholesky decomposition, but I am not sure how to deocmpose lower-upper triangular matrices)

Comment: Yes the diagonal $\Lambda$ can be seen as a scaling matrix, or the square thereof. Don't overthink it an don't let every paper intimidate you.